# Is the empty set an element of the set of all functions from natural numbers to natural numbers?

Tags: functions

I have doubt because $\text{Dom }\emptyset=\emptyset\neq\Bbb N$. Could anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your doubt.

The empty set can be looked at as a function $\varnothing\to\mathbb N$ but not as a function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$.

For every function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ there will be an element $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $(1,n)\in f$ and consequently $f\neq\varnothing$.